# Remove Item from Array using only word

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was wondering how to remove an item from an array only with the world, not array[0], etc.

Comment: Do you mean you have an array `['car', 'ball', 'computer']`, and you want to remove `ball` from it? You can use : `let newArr = oldArr.filter( e => e !== 'ball')`;

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov if you want to remove `ball` you should compare it the other way: `e !== 'ball'`

Comment: @KingGary exactly, fixed.

Comment: Hi @CandyCZ01, welcome to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow encourages questions that show what code you have tried, what result you got, and what result you expected. Please provide your code in order that others can help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
let input = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let output = input.filter(item => item !== 'b'); //["a", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splice` method for this and get element position with `indexOf`

**This will remove only first finded element**

```js
let testArray = ['1','2','3','4'];
let blackWorld = '2'
if(testArray.includes(blackWorld)) testArray.splice(testArray.indexOf(blackWorld),1)
console.log(testArray) // [ '1', '3', '4' ]
```

Or use `filter` method, so it will remove all elements if they equal your value for **1 blackworld**

```js
let testArray = ['1','2','3','4','2'];
let blackWorld = "2"
let newArray = testArray.filter(item => item !== blackWorld)
console.log(newArray) // [ '1', '3', '4' ]
```

**For array of blackworlds**

```js
let testArray = ['1','2','3','4'];
let blackWorlds = ['1','2']
let newArray = testArray.filter(item => !blackWorlds.includes(item))
console.log(newArray) // [ '3', '4' ]
```